# MySql GROUP_CONCAT function, correct syntax

Tags: mysql

I'm not a super expert of MySQL but I think I already correctly use this function.
I want to use a GROUP_CONCAT()

```
+----------+-------------------------------------------------+
| entry_id | image                                           |
+----------+-------------------------------------------------+
|      144 | 46335256-2020-08-06.jpg                         |
|      144 | 120360358-2020-08-06.jpg                        |
|      144 | photo-1500648767791-00dcc994a43e-2020-08-06.jpg |
|      146 | webdam-2020-08-06.web                           |
|      146 | 0_xMaFF2hSXpf_kIfG-2020-08-06.jpg               |
+----------+-------------------------------------------------+
```

I would like to get:

```
+----------+-------------------------------------------------+
| entry_id | images                                           |
+----------+-------------------------------------------------+
|      144 | 46335256-2020-08-06.jpg, 120360358-2020-08-06.jpg,photo-1500648767791-00dcc994a43e-2020-08-06.jpg                     
|      146 | webdam-2020-08-06.web, 0_xMaFF2hSXpf_kIfG-2020-08-06.jpg                             
+----------+-------------------------------------------------+
```

I tried with:

```
 SELECT entry_id, image GROUP_CONCAT(image) FROM images;
```

But it doesn't work.
Any suggestion?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Marco Disco, I think you should point out what MySQL version with you are using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GROUP_CONCAT() is an aggregate function like COUNT() and SUM(). Therefore you need GROUP BY to make it work correctly.

Try something like this.

```
SELECT entry_id, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(image) images
 FROM images
GROUP BY entry_id;
```

Comment: Add alias (`images` as OP wants) to aggregated column...

Comment: Oh, that's what he meant, eh? I thought he simply omitted the comma after `images` in his sample query.

Comment: No, look at the header of desired result... PS. Is this simple syntax was hard to OP, maybe column aliasing will occur to be hard too...